# How to hide borders of empty table (HTML, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to remove a HTML table completely from the screen and still be able to add rows to it later.  I have the following code to remove all rows from a table (basically, it sets the inner HTML of the table to ""):

```
function removeAllRows() {
    table = document.getElementById("myTable")
    table.innerHTML = ""
}
```

However, when this function is called, the table isn't completely removed...there's a small speck on the table, which I believe has to do with the 1 pixel border of a table element.

I'd like to modify this function to completely remove the table from the screen, which would basically be hiding the table border when the table is empty.

Is there something that I could put in the style block to do this?

Right now, my style block looks like:

```
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

`empty-cells: hide;` will hide the borders of empty cells, but not the border of the whole table if the whole table has no cells.

Is there any way to hide the border of an empty table?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umgcsbuv/)

Comment: Do you want to remove the table from the page completely?

Comment: You could use `jquery` and in the `removeAllRows` function add a class to the table which has a style of `border: 0px solid black;`. However this may only work with `Ajax` unless you refresh the page after adding the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just hide the table you can do this...

```
function removeAllRows() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable")
    // Checking that the table element exists before setting it to hidden to avoid nullreference exceptions.
    if(!!table){table.hidden = true;}
}
```

Comment: I've also seen pages which contain "a table that will contain data," and "a placeholder for use when the table is empty or not-there," both in the HTML (DOM) at the same time.  One or the other of the two is hidden.  Often it's some kind of "placeholder" so that the user won't be visually-surprised to see a table "magically appear" at a certain place on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the border programmatically. Add this line in removeAllRows()

```
table.style.border="0px";
```

Then in the addRow() method, add the border back:

```
table.style.border="1px solid black";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a *no border* class to you table

```
function removeAllRows() {
    table = document.getElementById("myTable")
    table.innerHTML = ""
    table.className = 'no-border';
}
```

And in you CSS file:

```
.no-border {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not manage to solve it with CSS alone. 
But you can either hide the table or just toggling the classlist property

```
if (table.children.length) {
    table.classList.toggle('border') // whatever should replace default
}
```